# lookup between two lists programmatically

Tags: lookup-column

i have two lists. the first list name is "cases" and the second list name is "issues". 
in the cases list i have a text column that holds a case number. in the issues list i have lookup column name "connceted case". i want this lookup column to do a lookup against the 
case number field in the cases list, and to retrieve the values from that field.

I also want to do this: i have a choice column which name is "status" in the cases list.
If the value of the status field is "closed" for a specific case item in the cases list, i want to make a restriction that the specific case item with the status of closed, wont be able to chooce in the lookup field connected case.

I dont know where to start, is this possible to do programmatically from visual studio??

**Update** 
i have tried the method now. The method adds the column just fine. 
But something is still wrong with the method, because when i add the method in my feature receiver for the site, it does the jobb for the lookup column, but i dont execute the following methods after the lookup methods. 
for example: Helpermethods.AddLockup, HelperMethods.CreateQuickLaunch.. it doesnt execute the CreateQuickLaunch

```
SPList sourceList = web.Lists["cases"];
         SPList dependList = web.Lists["issues"];

            string lookupColumn = dependList.Fields.AddLookup("connected case", sourceList.ID, true);
            SPFieldLookup primaryLookup = (SPFieldLookup)dependList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(lookupColumn);
            primaryLookup.LookupField = sourceList.Fields["casenumer"].InternalName;
            primaryLookup.Indexed = true;
            primaryLookup.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior.Restrict;
            primaryLookup.Update();

**//Why do i need this secondary column? I have just copy and paste this one from the article. What function does the Last Name field does in my situation?** 


            string strSecondaryCol = dependList.Fields.AddDependentLookup("Last Name", primaryLookup.Id);
            SPFieldLookup secondaryCol = (SPFieldLookup)dependList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(strSecondaryCol);
            secondaryCol.LookupField = sourceList.Fields["Last Name"].InternalName;
            secondaryCol.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Retrieving Values**
If you're running SharePoint 2010 the CAML has been extended to support joins via Lookup columns.

So you'll be able to write a single CAML query against the issues list with a join to the cases list to do the filtering and retrieve the information from both lists.

See [List Joins and Projections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539975.aspx)

If you're running a prior version then you need to do multiple queries and join the values yourselves as @Ray describes

**Limit Selects**
Regarding limiting selection to only non-closed item I'd recommend the following non-code solution:

1. In the Cases list create a calculated field with a formular like `IF([Status]="closed","",[Title])` (You can replace the `[Title]` part with whatever you want to show when selecting items
2. In the Issues list create the lookup column using the calculated field, but with [Title] as an additional field (Requires SP2010)
3. In views of Issues list don't use the lookup column, but instead the Lookup:Title column

This will create a column in cases which is blank for items you don't want to be able to select and happily enough SharePoint won't show blank items. The reason for including Title as an additional field and using that in views is that otherwise your views will show blank values when the corresponding case is closed.

**Info to update in Question**
If you followed my description of adding a calculated column to Cases which is blank when the case is closed (let's call this `CaseNumberIfNotClosed`) and otherwise has the value you want want to display (can be Title or custom field) (let's call that source field `CaseNumberAlways`)

Then what you need in the event receiver is something like (replace `CaseNumberIfNotClosed` and `CaseNumberAlways` with right names):

```
// Create look up field only allow selection of non closed cases
SPList sourceList = web.Lists["cases"]; 
SPList dependList = web.Lists["issues"]; 

// Create look up field only allow selection of non closed cases
string lookupColumn = dependList.Fields.AddLookup("Connected Case Selection", sourceList.ID, true); 
SPFieldLookup primaryLookup = (SPFieldLookup)dependList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(lookupColumn); 
primaryLookup.LookupField = sourceList.Fields["CaseNumberIfNotClosed"].InternalName; 
primaryLookup.Indexed = true; 
primaryLookup.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior.Restrict; 
primaryLookup.Update(); 

// Create additional field for using in views which has case number even if case is closed 
string strSecondaryCol = dependList.Fields.AddDependentLookup("Connected Case", primaryLookup.Id); 
SPFieldLookup secondaryCol = (SPFieldLookup)dependList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(strSecondaryCol); 
secondaryCol.LookupField = sourceList.Fields["CaseNumberAlways"].InternalName; 
secondaryCol.Update();
```

Comment: Yes iam running SharePoint 2010. thats nice to hear, that only one query is neded. But after i have retrieved the information, how do i handle this when people will add items to both of the list. Should it be in some listEvent or? 
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Added section about the lookup to the answer

Comment: Hey Per! 
Thanks for your suggestion it works fine doing this manually in sharepoint. But i dont understand, why cant i do this with code? i can se you mentioned "Regarding limiting selection to only non-closed item" but i dont really understand. isnt it possible to this with code?? 
Thanks so much to for your help! iam a beginner sharepoint developer, so many things are new to me.

Comment: Yes you can do all of the adding of fields through "code" (which I recommend) and you can also do all the work to make this in forms using code (which I DON'T recommend). But ALWAYS remember, that the most important skill for a SharePoint developer is not to write code unless there is a really good reason to do it.

Comment: all my fields are defined in XML from visual studio, shouldnt it be possible to create the calculated field and the formula there and also create the lookup field there? i have also created my custom views for the lists in visual studio, then i could define which columns i want to show in the views?

Comment: thanks that is a really good point from you! but the reason i want to this in code, is that i work with a team site that is deployed using a feature, and all of the sites content is packaged into the feature. This was the requirment from my project leader. Do as much minimal manually sharepoint configuration as possible.

Comment: I also recommended that you defined the fields/views through "code" (XML or "real" code). But the easiest way to generate the XML is to make the fields in the UI and the use PowerShell or [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com) to get the xml

Comment: i have already generated the fields succesfully. so thats solved. i have just crated the formula succesfully for the calculated field, and it works fine it gets the values. 
But now idont know how to "connect" the lookup field in the issues list to the cases list? i dont know which xml properties are required to this connection. i should mention that my lists are not list definitions that are created through xml, they are created through csharp code. 
The properties that i have so far in my lookup column is:
ID, 
DisplayName,
Type,
Group, 
Name.
which more are required to do the "connection"?

Comment: i tried to set the property in the lookup column to List="Lists/cases" thats the url of my cases list. But it doesnt work??

Comment: Getting lookup to work through XML is tricky which is why people useally add them in an FeatureReceiver using [SPFieldCollection.AddLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436747.aspx) and [SPFieldCollection.AddDependentLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.adddependentlookup.aspx)

Comment: yes now i have seen many articles about that, so i will create my lookup thorugh code. thanks for the links to the articles, so my "dependlist" should be the issues list, where the lookup column will be added? 
And which one of the articles shoud i follow? 
Thanks for all your help Per!

Comment: You can use any of the articles (the second just has extra code to move field in forms and add them to views). Your `sourceList` is Cases and `dependList` is issues

Comment: I have tried the method now. Read my updated question, where i have posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

To do this programmatically, as you described, one option would be to execute a series of CAML Queries against the target lists:

```
//grab the list - several different ways to accomplish this - this is only one particular way
SPList targetList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["titleOfList"];

//build the CAML Query
SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
String camlQuery = @"somequerygoeshere";

SPListItemCollection filteredItems = targetList.GetItems(spQuery);

//do something with your filtered list of items down here
//...
```

Details of how to build a CAML Query for SharePoint can be found [here.](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list) Also search the sharepoint.stackexchange as there are lots of excellent discussions on building CAML for SharePoint.

Comment: i know about how to get list, and i have also read about that you can use CAML querys for a problem like that i described. So i should write a CAML query against the cases list and then retrieve all case numbers and filter thoose against thoose that have the status of closed? 
It would be nice with some examples querys, because i find it hard to query against many columns and many lists. 
Thansk for your reply!

Comment: As I hint, I would suggest taking a look at using a CAML Query builder. Search 
 There are some good free ones out there, but if you read some basic articles on CAML, building even a more complex query should be easy.